# openhtmltopdf can't load the font while running from docker container

Tags: docker, openhtmltopdf

I have the following setup:

```
@Value("classpath:fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf")
private lateinit var regularFont: org.springframework.core.io.Resource

...

private val regular: FSSupplier<InputStream> by lazy {
   FSSupplier<InputStream> { regularFont.inputStream }
}

...

val processor = BufferedImagePageProcessor(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 1.0)
Java2DRendererBuilder().apply {
     withHtmlContent(html, "https://some.org")
     useFastMode()
     toSinglePage(processor)
     useEnvironmentFonts(false)
     useFont(regular, "Poppins")
 }.run {
     try {
         runFirstPage()
     } catch (e: Throwable) {
         log.error("Could not generate preview", e)
     }
}
```

it works perfectly if I run the app locally, but once the same code executed from docker container, it throws the following warning and no image is generated:

```
com.openhtmltopdf.exception WARNING:: Couldn't load font. Please check that it is a valid truetype font. => java.io.IOException:: Problem reading font data.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to copy the font(s) folder to the Docker container and then specify the location in your application.yml/settings file to read from during runtime.

I assume that all your font files (.ttf) are in the src/main/resources folder. Here is a sample Dockerfile that can copy the fonts folder:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
WORKDIR /src/
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests
WORKDIR /assets/
RUN jar xf /src/target/*.jar  --> this step extracts the jar file which contains the classes\font folder
WORKDIR /app
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE cloud
COPY --from=builder /assets/ /app/ --> this step copies the classes\fonts to your docker container app folder
COPY --from=builder /src/target/*.jar test-application.jar
```